# Xpath expression to select all tags after <script>.....</script>

Tags: xpath

I have some problem getting all the HTML tags after `<script>`...`<script/>` using XPath.

My HTML:

```
<table dir="rtl"...>
    <tbody>
    <tr>..</tr>
    <script src = get.aspx?type=js&file=ajax&rev=3 ....>
    <script language="JavaScript".....>
    <script>...<script>
    <tr>..</tr>
    <tr>..</tr>
    <tr>..</tr>
    <tr>..</tr>
    <tr>..</tr>
```

I want to get all tags after the script tag in XPath.

This is the link to the web page: [source](http://kooora.com/?c=6423)

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using XPath for this if you want to get the remainder of the document. SAX parsing is likely going to be more efficient. When you implement a callback function for starting parsing of an element, check if it's a `script` and set a `BOOL hitJavascript` to `YES`, then when you parse `tr`'s check `if(hitJavascript)`, and then do what you want with the inner `td`'s when you're inside the `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

The html you posted has a `<script>...<script>`<sup>1</sup> after `<script language="JavaScript".....>`, but [the source](http://kooora.com/?c=6423) does not have the extra `<script>` tag(s).

For the source HTML, this XPath works:

```
//script[@language="JavaScript"]/following::tr
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Did you mean `<script>...</script>`?

Comment: thank .this works but only get text within script ,i want to select all <tr> after the script .

Comment: In that case, change `following::*` --> `following::tr`

Comment: in every <tr> after the script there is many td .example  the second <tr> contain many (td id = "jm0x1")(td id = "jm0x2") but i can't access them .i need help pls

Comment: thank you darvids0n for your answer .i am new to html parsing and i am using HPPLE to parse html on iphone how how i use SAX parsing .